# Android GPS Location Inaccurate

Tags: android, gps, location, android-gps

So I have a timer I am running every 10 seconds that updates my GPS location and inserts it into my database. The problem is the location is never accurate, and I don't mean by meters I mean by half a mile to a mile sometimes. I have tried multiple settings on my phone and none of them correct this issue. I have also used the Stride GPS tracking app along side my app and Stride has pinpoint accuracy as to where mine is all over the place. Any suggestions?

This is my call:

```
Location loc = GPS.sharedInstance(Dashboard.this).getLastKnownLocation();
                            double e_lat = GPS.sharedInstance(Dashboard.this).getLatitude();
                            double e_long = GPS.sharedInstance(Dashboard.this).getLongitude();
                            GPS.sharedInstance(Dashboard.this).updateLocation(e_lat, e_long);
```

GPS.java:

```
public Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(_activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        _isPermissionEnabled = false;
    } else {
        if (_canGetLocation) {
            if (_isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                _locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (_locationManager != null)
                {
                    _location = _locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


                    if (_location != null)
                    {
                        _latitude = _location.getLatitude();
                        _longitude = _location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (_isGPSEnabled)
            {


                if (_location == null)
                {

                    _locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (_locationManager != null)
                    {
                        _location = _locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


                        if (_location != null)
                        {
                            _latitude = _location.getLatitude();
                            _longitude = _location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return _location;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (_locationManager != null) {
        _latitude = _location.getLatitude();
    }

    return _latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (_locationManager != null) {
        _longitude = _location.getLongitude();
    }

    return _longitude;
}
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the GPS to get a fix before logging it? You might want to hold off logging until the accuracy is within a acceptable range.

Comment: And also make sure that your gps is on Maximum Accuracy..

Comment: Are checking the location's provider to make sure you are getting a GPS point? If it is network, those could be 1000m+ accuracy (0.6+ miles).